# Move button below text on mobile only

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to figure this out. My goal is to have the button as it is now for desktop and for mobile screen instead of being under the image to go under the last paragraph of text. I've tried to use the display:block; and margin-top but it doesn't seem to work in any way. Any idea if this is achievable?

```html
<style type="text/css">
   @media only screen and (max-width:640px) 
   {
 
.button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
   }
</style>

<table bgcolor="#F6F6F6" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!---->
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" role="presentation" style="min-width: 100%; " class="a">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table bgcolor="#F6F6F6" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td width="24"></td>
                <td>
                  <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius:8px;border:solid #E0E0E0 1px;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td height="24"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="271">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td valign="top">
                                                                        <![endif]-->
                              <table width="294" class="w100pc hauto" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="24"></td>
                                  <td>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="pc">
                                          <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;color:#111111;" target="_blank">
                                            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" style="display:block;" border="0" width="230" height="265" class="w100pc hauto">
                                          </a>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td height="24"></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>
                                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#E5133A" style="border-radius:5px;">
                                            <tr>
                                              <td height="15" colspan="3"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td width="20"></td>
                                              <td class="button" style="font-family:'Roboto',Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:16px;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:500;text-align:center;">
                                                <a href="" target="_blank" alias="Perfect-Choice" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;"> BUTTON </a>
                                              </td>
                                              <td width="20"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td height="15" colspan="3"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td height="30"></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                  <td width="10" class="w24"></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td valign="top">
                                                                            <![endif]-->
                              <table width="294" class="w100pc hauto" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="left">
                                <tr>
                                  <td width="10" class="w24"></td>
                                  <td>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                      <tr></tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td height="40"></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="fallback-bold" style="color:#1A1A1A;font-family:'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:24px;line-height:28px;"> TExt </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td height="24"></td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="fallback" style="color:#1A1A1A;font-family:'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:400;font-size:16px;line-height:22px;"> Last paragrapgh. </td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td height="24"></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                  <td width="24"></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <![endif]-->
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
                <td width="24"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!---->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is this so complicated table? Why did you used table like this?

Comment: this is html email standards so it can render well in all email clients

Comment: There isn't a good way to do this given your structure and the fact this is for email. Traditionally you could use `flex` and the `order` property. It would be supported on all emails except for outlook on windows. If this is fine, I can post a solution.